# delete[] array caused a breakpoint

Tags: c++

I am trying to move a part of my code from main function to the additional void function, but I keep getting a problem with deleting allocated memory in the end. By that moment my program did not printed out my array as it should have. So i am looking for a tip how i can fix this.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void push(char* C, int size, istream &in);
void print_str(char* word, int length);

int main()
{
    char* C = new char[0];
    int size = 0;
    cout << "input your text: ";
    push(C, size, cin);
    print_str(C, size);
    delete[] C;
    return 0;
};


void print_str(char* word, int length) {
    for (int k = 0; k < length; k++)
    {
        cout << word[k];
    }

    cout << " ";
};

void push(char* C, int size, istream& in) {
    while (1) {
        char current = in.get();
        if (current == '\n')
            break;
        else {
            char* text1 = new char[size];
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                text1[i] = C[i];
            delete[] C;

            C = new char[size + 1];

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                C[i + 1] = text1[i];
            delete[] text1;

            C[0] = current;
        }
        size++;
    }
}
```

[Breakpoint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17uel.png)

Comment: Modifying function argument won't affect caller's local variables. You can use reference. (to search for question for use in duplicate vote...)

Comment: If this is not a school assignment, I strongly suggest to forget this new/pointer stuff *completely*.

Comment: Assignment to `C` inside `push` is not visible to the caller. In `main`, `C` becomes a dangling pointer since `push` deallocated the memory it originally pointed to.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

`push` changes the value of `C`, so it must `return` the new value so that the other code can see the change. Like this (for instance)

```
int main() {
  ...
  C = push(C, size, cin);
  ...
}

char* push(char* C, int size, istream& in) {
while (1) {
    char current = in.get();
    if (current == '\n')
        break;
    else {
        char* text1 = new char[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            text1[i] = C[i];
        delete[] C;

        C = new char[size + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            C[i + 1] = text1[i];
        delete[] text1;

        C[0] = current;
    }
    size++;
  }
  return C;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to define c as pointer to pointer , because changing c in push scope won't change value of c in main

here's the changed code

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void push(char** C, int size, istream& in);
void print_str(char* word, int length);
int main()
{
    char* C = new char[0];
    int size = 0;
    cout << "input your text: ";
    push(&C, size, cin);
    print_str(C, size);
    delete[] C;
    return 0;
};


void print_str(char* word, int length) {
    for (int k = 0; k < length; k++)
    {
        cout << word[k];
    }

    cout << " ";
};
void push(char** C, int size, istream& in) {
    while (1) {
        char current = in.get();
        if (current == '\n')
            break;
        else {
            char* text1 = new char[size];
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                text1[i] = (*C)[i];
            delete[] C;

            *C = new char[size + 1];

            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
                C[i + 1] = text1[i];
            delete[] text1;

            (*C)[0] = current;
        }
        size++;
    }
}
```

also you can make more efficient algorithms to reach your end ,instead of allocating and deallocating memory for each character witch is costy